# 'System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid' does not contain a definition for 'RenderControl'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql, export-to-excel

i am newbie using MVC 3 and linq to SQL in asp.net , i am trying to Export my webgrid data to excel sheet, but it throws error:

```
'System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid' does not contain a definition for 'RenderControl' and no extension method 'RenderControl' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

i am posting code so you guys could help me out.
Code:

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Helpers;
using EmployeeAttendance_app.Models;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;


namespace EmployeeAttendance_app.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Precise Technology Consultants";
            var DataContext = new EmployeeAtdDataContext();
            //var EmployeeAtd = DataContext.GetAttendance_Sp();
            IEnumerable<GetAtdRecord_SpResult> EmployeeAtd = DataContext.GetAtdRecord_Sp(null).ToList();
            return View(EmployeeAtd);

        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult ViewData() 
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult ToExcel()
        {
            var DataContext = new EmployeeAtdDataContext(); 

            IEnumerable<GetAtdRecord_SpResult> EmployeeAtd = DataContext.GetAtdRecord_Sp(null).ToList();

            var grid = new WebGrid(EmployeeAtd, defaultSort: "EmplID");
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=AttendanceSheet.xls");
            Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
            Response.Charset = "";
            System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            grid.RenderControl(htw);
            Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is view where it should dispaly data and then clicking Export should export file
VIEW:

```
@using EmployeeAttendance_app.Models



<div>

@{

    var grid = new WebGrid(ViewData.Model, defaultSort: "EmplID");

}

@grid.GetHtml()

 @using (Html.BeginForm("ToExcel","Home",FormMethod.Post))
{
    <button type="submit" >To Excel</button>
}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should name the parameter for your data:

```
var grid = new WebGrid(source: ViewData.Model, defaultSort: "EmplID");
```

Also the source needs to be of type `IEnumerable<object>`, so if your Model class doesn't implement `IEnumerable<object>`, you should change it or specify the property of the model to use as the source data for the WebGrid helper.